# Стоит ли создавать XML карту сайта,если максимум в ней 20 страниц?

Tags: seo, sitemap

Надо ли создавать XML карту сайта, если в карте максимум 20 страниц?

Comment: для более эффективной индексации страниц ботами наверное

Comment: Смотря какие цели у Вашего проекта

Comment: моя цель чтобы сайт был в топе с конкурирующими. Это небольшой интернет магазин,с максимум 10-20 товаров

Comment: Тогда однозначно стоит

Comment: @Дмитрий спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML-карта – это еще один плюс в копилку поисковой оптимизации.

Answer (score 1):

нет не стоит, она нужна для больших сайтов, для тех у кого некоторые разделы недоступны в навигации или имеются изолированные страницы. Но даже если так наличие наличие ссылки на документ в xml не гарантирует его сканирование.

Comment: больше для личного опыта попробовать хочу,я думаю хуже не будет

Answer (score 1):

Это вам надо решить самостоятельно. Проверьте что Гугл говорит об этом в своем руководстве **[О файлах Sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184)**:

> Нужен ли мне файл Sitemap?
>   Если страницы файла корректно связаны друг с другом, поисковые роботы могут обнаружить большую часть материалов. Тем не менее с помощью файла Sitemap можно оптимизировать сканирование сайта, особенно в следующих случаях:
>
> Размер сайта очень велик. Поисковые роботы Google могут пропустить
>   недавно созданные или измененные страницы.
>
> Сайт содержит большой архив
>   страниц, которые не связаны друг с другом. Чтобы они были успешно
>   просканированы, их можно перечислить в файле Sitemap.
>
> Ваш сайт создан
>   недавно, и на него указывает мало ссылок. Робот Googlebot и другие
>   поисковые роботы сканируют Интернет, переходя по ссылкам с одной
>   страницы на другую. Если на ваш сайт указывает мало ссылок, его будет
>   сложно найти.
>
> На сайте используется мультимедийный контент, он
>   отображается в Новостях Google или использует другие аннотации,
>   совместимые с файлами Sitemap. Из файлов Sitemap поисковая система
>   может получать дополнительную информацию для показа в результатах
>   поиска.
>
> Даже если вы создали файл Sitemap, это не гарантирует, что
>   Google будет сканировать и индексировать все ваши страницы, так как
>   эти процедуры выполняются при помощи сложных алгоритмов. В большинстве
>   случаев эти файлы приносят пользу и не приводят к ошибкам.